# Make ribbon-attached blocks appear the same size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap grid system to create "blocks" of different sizes on my page. Some of those need a ribbon (e.g. "new" products). The problem is, that the way I created the ribbons (the only way I know how to) means that I have to wrap the contents of the block and create a padding around the box, so the ribbon can "wrap around" it and create the required illusion.

This, however, also means that the boxes are slighty smaller than the should be, namely the padding I have to apply for the ribbon.

Here is a demo of how it looks currently: [fiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/kpopsj5x/)

**CSS**

```
.row {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
}

.block {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
}

.block-inner {
    background: #fcc;
    padding: 15px;
}

div.ribbon {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 88px;
    height: 86px;
}

div#no-ribbon {
    background: #ccf;
}

div.ribbon-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: -15px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;

    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;

    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 block">
            <div class="ribbon">
                <div class="ribbon-text">New!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="block-inner">
                <p>Some awesome text and imagery, whatever</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" id="no-ribbon">
            <p>A block with its "actual" size</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the visible left borders are not aligned. Technically of course, this is very logical. But, from user perspective, it just looks "off".

How can I make this work, so that the left border of a block *with* ribbon lines up with the left border of blocks *without* ribbon?

Comment: Try not use different markup for blocks: wrap all blocks and add padding, just for those which have ribbon add - a ribbon. Other way would be to put the ribbon in block and use for example: `position: absolute; left: -5px; top: -5px'` (no wrapping).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kpopsj5x/5/

Comment: @skobaljic Every block has the same html currently, the `#no-ribbon` block was just for the fiddle. but, not every `.col-` element is a block. and when they are near, the problem is seen

Comment: @FlorianPeschka how did u resolve this? i would like to see the solution :)

Comment: @KAD As of yet, I haven't. I will try out the solutions posted as soon as I can (Monday) in my reference project and accept the one that helped me the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated and Working**

Try `margin-left: -5px;` to the block.

```
.block-inner {
    background: #fcc;
    padding: 15px;
    /* Add this */
    margin-left: -5px;
}

div.ribbon {
    margin-left: -5px;
}

div.ribbon + .block-inner {
    margin-right: -5px;
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kpopsj5x/5/**

Comment: Then the right border won't line up - you can see that in your fiddle, too.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka Check now?

Comment: This solution is IMHO the simplest and most elegant. Works like a charm.

Comment: It is more quick-fix-the-hole than simplest solution. If he adds (and he will) another block in row than he loses all the bootstrap spacings, check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpopsj5x/6/). With my solution it would be [different](https://jsfiddle.net/coh3gfcx/), everything in place. Think we should encourage people to code correct way.

Comment: I do not say it does not work, it places the badge correctly, but it breaks the Bootstrap's layout. Looking from that point, it does not 'work for all the cases'.

Answer (score 2):

Moving left the inner block after positing it relative and increase the width a bit, as well as move the ribbon 5 pixels to the left :

```
.block-inner {
    background: #fcc;
    padding: 15px;

    // newly added css
    position: relative;
    left:-5px;

    //Also increase the width of the inner block
    width:96.7%;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
 div.ribbon {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;

        // move the ribbon also -5px
        left: -5px;
        width: 88px;
        height: 86px;
    }
```

Comment: I tried it in the fiddle, but then the ribbon is no longer wrapping the block, instead it's inside of it.

Comment: i have edited the ribbon css also, i think its fine now

Comment: I have also increased the width by %, it's working fine now

Answer (score 1):

You need to restructure your HTML and bit of CSS code.

[image]

```css
#no-ribbon .block-inner {
  background: #ccf none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 block">
      <div class="ribbon">
        <div class="ribbon-text">New!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-inner">
        <p>Some awesome text and imagery, whatever</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 block" id="no-ribbon">
      <div class="block-inner">
        <p>A block with its "actual" size</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/kpopsj5x/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make it simple, no need to put new html element for "New!" badge, just make an image with text:

[image: Badge New!]

and create a pseudo element:

```css
.row {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #efefef;
}
.block-inner {
    background: none white;
}
.block {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
}
.block-inner {
    background: #fcc;
    padding: 15px;
}
.badge-new::before {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    top: -3px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 88px;
    height: 86px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/quoTy.png');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="block-inner badge-new">
                <p>Some awesome text and imagery, whatever</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="block-inner">
                <p>A block with its "actual" size</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```